# echoing Command to cron.d

Tags: shell-script, cron, io-redirection, quoting

I am trying to append/echo a command to cron.d. However, when running the script that echoes the command:

```
echo */2 * * * * /usr/bin/aws ssm-send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters '{"commands":["echo {{ssm:/mr2/cloudwatch-custom}}"]"}' --instance-ids "$INSTANCE_ID" --region us-east-1 >> /etc/cron.d/lvm_disk_space
```

I cat out the file that it writes to and it has this:

```
*/2 boot-finished cloud-config.txt datasource handlers obj.pkl scripts sem user-data.txt user-data.txt.i vendor-data.txt vendor-data.txt.i boot-finished cloud-config.txt datasource handlers obj.pkl scripts sem user-data.txt user-data.txt.i vendor-data.txt vendor-data.txt.i boot-finished cloud-config.txt datasource handlers obj.pkl scripts sem user-data.txt user-data.txt.i vendor-data.txt vendor-data.txt.i boot-finished cloud-config.txt datasource handlers obj.pkl scripts sem user-data.txt user-data.txt.i vendor-data.txt vendor-data.txt.i /usr/bin/aws ssm-send-command --document-name AWS-RunShellScript --parameters {"commands":["echo {{ssm:/mr2/cloudwatch-custom}}"]"} --instance-ids  --region us-east-1
```

I'm assuming the `*` is messing things up. When I try to wrap it in quotes, I always get:

```
echo "*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/aws ssm-send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters '{"commands":["echo {{ssm:/mr2/cloudwatch-custom}}"]"}' --instance-ids "$INSTANCE_ID" --region us-east-1" >> /etc/cron.d/lvm_disk_space

./user-data.txt: line 30: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./user-data.txt: line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Is there a safe way to escape quotes?

Answer (score 4):

Your issue with the first command is that the `*` characters are unquoted.  The shell will therefore expand them to any matching filenames in the current directory.

Your issue with the second command is that the command contains both single and double quotes, so you can't reliably just quote the crontab entry with double quotes as you try to do.  You would have to rewrite it so that it first of all only contains a single type of quotes (e.g. double quotes), and then use the other types of quotes (single quotes) to quote the full command.  The crontab entry also contains a typo (which I'm not going to try to correct, because I don't know what it *should* be) in that it has an uneven number of double quotes.

A better way is to use a quoted here-document:

```sh
cat >>/etc/cron.d/lvm_disk_space  <<'END_CRON'
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/aws ssm-send-command --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --parameters '{"commands":["echo {{ssm:/mr2/cloudwatch-custom}}"]"}' --instance-ids "$INSTANCE_ID" --region us-east-1
END_CRON
```

This uses a quoted here-document redirection to write the literal text to the end of the file.  The contents of the here-document will not be "poked at" (expanded or otherwise modified) by the shell due to the quotes around the initial `END_CRON` tag.

Note that your command still contains an open double quote that you will have to fix yourself:

```
["echo {{ssm:/mr2/cloudwatch-custom}}"]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Correctly quoted line should look like this:

```
$ echo \*/2\ \*\ \*\ \*\ \*\ /usr/bin/aws\ ssm-send-command\ --document-name\ \"AWS-RunShellScript\"\ --parameters\ \'\{\"commands\":\[\"echo\ \{\{ssm:/mr2/cloudwatch-custom\}\}\"\]\"\}\'\ --instance-ids\ \"\$INSTANCE_ID\"\ --region\ us-east-1
```

Of course, I didn't come up with this crazy quoting by myself, I used this script that uses `%q` specifier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

read 
printf "%q\n" "$REPLY" | tr '\n' ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

try breaking into two string

```
echo "*/2 * * * *" /usr/bin/aws ssm-send-command (...) >> /etc/cron.d/lvm_disk_space
```

this way `*` won't be expanded to local filenames, and you get remaining argument.

Note that external quote are removed.

e.g.

```
--document-name "AWS-RunShellScript"
```

is expanded as

```
--document-name AWS-RunShellScript
```